# Rewarding additional answers

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

I am relatively new to SO and perhaps this has been discussed before. I did not find exactly this question when searching Meta, so here goes.

Occasionally, when reading answers to a question that I posted, there is a second answer that also deserves to be accepted because it answers a different part of the question. Together, both answers comprise the actual solution.

Is there a way to reward multiple correct answers?

I tried assigning a bounty-after-the-fact to the second answer, but once the first answer is marked "accepted", the bounty option disappears. What to do?

Comment: I would have said "a bounty". But it disappears? That shouldn't happen to my knowledge. But then again I know very little....

Comment: Remember, you can always give an upvote.

Comment: Sounds like awarding an assist score...

Comment: Are you sure the question is eligible for a bounty? You can't start one until 2 days after it was asked.

Comment: The message about starting a bounty in two days disappears after one question is marked accepted. Did I miss something?

Comment: @gibberish The message saying you can;t disappears. You would not be able to no matter whether there is an accepted answer. You can start a bounty--once the question is older than 2 days.

Comment: @gibberish The system assumes that you wouldn't need a bounty since you've marked an answer as accepted. The actual "start a bounty" link *will* appear once 2 days have passed, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always start a bounty on a question that is older than 2 days. It doesn't matter who asked the question and/or whether some answer was already accepted. Of course you need to have enough reputation (75) and no more than maximum number of active bounties (3).

I find it optimal, that only one answer per question can be accepted. It helps people coming with similar problems searching for solutions to quickly spot what they are looking for.

To sum up, you have three options how to reward an answer:

1. Accept it (+15 rep., your question, one answer only)
2. Upvote (+10 rep., any answers, 200 daily limit for upvoted user)
3. Start a bounty (starting at +50 rep.)

It is a perfectly valid reason to start a bounty on a question with accepted answer just to award the author of any answer. There is more information in [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty), the most important rules:

> Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
>   There can only be 1 active bounty per question at any given time.
>
> Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty, and may only
>   have a maximum of 3 active bounties at any given time.

You can even award the same answer repeatedly, or award two or more answers for the same question.

And **here is the only space for improvement I personally see**, that is, if you would like to reward two answers on the same question, which were both correct and both authors showed lots of effort, you can't give the same award to each one of them. If you give let's say `+100` to the first one, you need to give at least `+200` to the second one. Since every time you start a bounty on a question repeatedly, you need to give at least double the previous amount (`+500` is the limit).